# How to avoid the overwriting of checkbutton in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My `checkbutton` is overwriting with buttons. How to give `x axis` and `y axis` to Buttons?

I tried to use `l.place()` instead of `l.pack()`, but it is not returning anything. What should I use instead of `l.pack()` to avoid this overwrite?

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import tkinter.filedialog


class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", 
command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", 
command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))


#This is not in class    
def call():

    # add to scrolled frame

    data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
    variables = []

    # add widgets to scrolled frame - as parent you have to use `sf.frame` instead of `sf`
    for txt in data:
        var = tk.IntVar()
        variables.append(var)
        l = tk.Checkbutton(sf.frame, text=txt, variable=var)
        l.pack()



root = tk.Tk()

sf = ScrolledFrame(root)
sf.pack()


btn1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Source Path", command = call)
btn1.place(x = 0,y = 0 )

ent1 = tkinter.Entry(root)
ent1.place(x = 100,y = 0,width = 200,height=25)

btn1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="destination")
btn1.place(x = 0,y = 40 )

ent1 = tkinter.Entry(root)
ent1.place(x = 100,y = 40,width = 200,height=25)

root.mainloop()
```

**Incorrect Output:**

[image]

**Expected Ouput:**

The `checkbutton` should start below the `Destination Button`.

Comment: You should **not** mix the different layout methods inside the one container. The `.place` method is not pleasant to work with, I suggest you use `.grid`, it's a lot easier to use correctly.

Comment: i tried (l.grid(sticky="w")) but i am getting the same result @PM2Ring

Comment: You need to use either `pack` or `grid` for all your widgets, the checkbuttons but also `btn1` and `ent1`. It is because the buttons and entries are placed that they overlap with the packed checkbuttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, do not mix various layouts.
Then, it is likely better to have the entry boxes and buttons in the frame you are creating.

Here is what I propose, you can change to another layout if you prefer:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import tkinter.filedialog

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

        btn1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Source Path", command = call)
        btn1.pack()

        ent1 = tkinter.Entry(root)
        ent1.pack()

        btn1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="destination")
        btn1.pack()

        ent1 = tkinter.Entry(root)
        ent1.pack()
        self.pack()

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))


def call():
    # add components to scrolled frame    
    data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
    variables = []

    # add widgets to scrolled frame - as parent you have to use `sf.frame` instead of `sf`
    for txt in data:
        var = tk.IntVar()
        variables.append(var)
        l = tk.Checkbutton(sf.frame, text=txt, variable=var)
        l.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
sf = ScrolledFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Your tick boxes will appear when you click on the button.

Comment: Glad I  could help.